# mudar String.xml pela classe java

Tags: java, android, string, xml

Olá, queria saber se é possível modificar uma String da pasta values através de um click de um button.

essas são as String.xml

```
<string name="app_name">FC MANAGER</string>
<string name="goleiro_1">1 Diego Alves</string>
<string name="goleiro_2">37 César</string>
<string name="zagueiro_1">15 Rever</string>
<string name="zagueiro_2">4 Juan</string>
<string name="zagueiro_3">44 Rhodolfo</string>
<string name="zagueiro_4">43 Léo Duarte</string>
<string name="lateraldireito_1">2 Rodinei</string>
<string name="lateraldireito_2">21 Pará</string>
<string name="lateralesquerdo_1">6 Renê</string>
<string name="lateralesquerdo_2">13 Miguel Trauco</string>
<string name="volante_1">8 Cuéllar</string>
<string name="volante_2">14 Jonas</string>
<string name="volante_3">27 Romulo</string>
<string name="meiocampo_1">10 Diego</string>
<string name="meiocampo_2">7 Everton Ribeiro</string>
<string name="meiocampo_3">11 Lucas Paquetá</string>
<string name="meiocampo_4">18 Jean Lucas</string>
<string name="atacante_1">19 Henrique Dourado</string>
<string name="atacante_2">20 Vinicius Junior</string>
<string name="atacante_3">29 Lincoln</string>
<string name="atacante_4">23 Geuvânio</string>
<string name="tecnico">Barbieri</string>
```

Queria saber se é possível através de um comando na classe java mudar uma string que for selecionada.

Comment: Utilize *SharedPreferences* ao invés do arquivo *String.xml*

Answer (score 3):

Quando você fornece um valor como um recurso (*Resource*) ele não pode ser modificado em tempo de execução. Por exemplo, as imagens que você tem na sua pasta *drawable* não podem ser modificadas em tempo de execução e isso se aplica para *Strings.xml* e a pasta *Values*.

Se você quer uma *string* que seja modificada em tempo de execução, não a crie  como um recurso.